# How to generate xml sample form xsd with XMLSchema:sequence

Tags: xml, xsd

How to create xml sample from xsp with contains XMLSchema:sequence ?

I tried http://www.xsd2xml.com/  but it returns error

```
Error!!!
The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:sequence' element is not supported in this context.
```

instead of sample.

Original xsd has types in separate files and I copied those types to end of this xsd as Maybe this causes the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSD is missing the following line near the bottom prior to the last `xs:sequence`:

```
<xs:complexType name="Property">
```

Adding that line will complete the last declaration,

```
<xs:complexType name="Property">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="stringVal" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="dateVal" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="booleanVal" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="integerVal" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="decimalVal" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
          <xs:totalDigits value="15"/>
          <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and make your XSD valid.